# Custom Fonts not working in System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, custom-font

I am feeding html into a webBrowser control where the html includes a custom font:

```
@font-face {    src: url(../fonts/myfont.ttf) format("truetype"); }
```

The html references the font but the rendered page ignores the font references and my font is not rendered.

If I debug the code and take the generated html that is provided to the webBrowser, put in a local file and render it with IE (or firefox, or Chrome) it works fine - the font is used.

Originally I had a problem with a non-installable font. But I resolved that which is evident by the fact that IE standalone is able to render the font.

Originally I had the @font-face in the css file. I also tried putting it into an embedded style element. I also tried changing the url to be an absolute url.

None of these worked.

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?